# Install rJava library fail to find path

Tags: r

I try to install rJava package using this way in windows

```
install.packages("rJava")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.2/rJava_1.0-6.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1245703 bytes (1.2 MB)
downloaded 1.2 MB

package ‘rJava’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpOqiB8n\downloaded_packages
```

And when I try to call the library I receive this error

```
library(rJava)
```

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’:
> .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
> call: inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...)
> error: unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2/rJava/libs/x64/rJava.dll':
> LoadLibrary failure:  The specified device could not be found. unit

How is it possible to install this library with an alternative way or is there anything I could fix?

Comment: Do you have java installed on your computer? The R package will not be able to install the system java dependency. What version of java do you have installed on your computer? One of those most common mistakes is to use 64-bit R but only have 32-bit Java installed.

Comment: @MrFlick here is the version of Java I have `java 19.0.1 2022-10-18
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 19.0.1+10-21)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.0.1+10-21, mixed mode, sharing)` and R from the rstudio `R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt) -- "Innocent and Trusting"
Copyright (C) 2022 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)`

Comment: maybe add java as environment variable? Search for Environment Variables then select Edit the system environment variables. Set path for JAVA_HOME.